# Список в классе почему-то является общим для всех объектов

Tags: python, ооп, list

Имеется небольшой класс с полем-списком:

```
class Country:
    citizens = []
```

Конструктор класса наполняет список 4 объектами другого класса:

```
def __init__(self):
    for i in range(4):
        self.citizens.append(Citizen())
```

Создается два объекта класса `Country`, однако каждый объект имеет в своем списке не 4 жителя, а 8, то есть жителей своей страны и в дополнении второй, что не предусматривалось. Я пришел к выводу что этот список по какой то причине является общим для всех объектов в классе. Почему так происходит, и какая альтернатива спискам в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`citizens` Создайте на уровне экземпляра класса

```
def __init__(self):
    self.citizens = []
    for i in range(4):
        self.citizens.append(Citizen())
```

Списки в Python - изменяемые коллекции  + Вы обьявили `citizens` переменной класса (общая для всех экземпляров)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю как работают переменные всего класса и конкретно объекта. Провожу себе паралель с кейвордом   static в C#, и не могу понять в каком случае объявленная в классе переменная является статичной, а в каком нет. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: @ЯковБайдук если объявлена с помощью self - переменная экземпляра, а в теле класса - это переменная класса

Comment: В питоне прикол ещё в том, что пока вы не присвоили переменной экземпляра какое-то значение, питон вам выдаёт вместо неё переменную класса с этим же именем (но без `self.`). В `C#` же статическая переменная и обычная чётко разделены и никак не связаны, поэтому путаницы меньше.